# vim ignores a path

Tags: vim, autocomplete, tags

I'm inside `~/.cache/jhbuild/build/<project>`

I have tags generated with:

```
$ make ctags
```

if I run

```
$ vim -t main
```

I get

```
E433: No hay archivo de etiquetas
E426: No se encontró la etiqueta: main
```

but doing (deactivate all config for vim):

```
$ vim -u NONE -t main
```

vim open the file with main tag correctly.

I can find the culprit for this behaviour, but there's something strange I  found:

dir autocompletion doesn't work for the path of this directory with all the plugins enabled

```
:e /home/alberto/.cache/jhbuild/<tab><tab>
```

do not find `build` as a possible autocompletion

if I run with vim -u NONE that autocompletion works. I guess that's the main problem, vim ignores this path for some reason with all my config enabled.

So my question is: How one can disable autocompletion for a directory in vim?

Answer (score 1):

I found the culprit:

```
wildignore=*/build/*,*/target/*
```

it is a nasty wildignore although it correctly suggest to ignore built files.

Indeed I would prefer to generate tag files inside source folder to move around inside same dir an not just with tag definitions